# what can be the possible regex for validating comma separated strings against set of given string?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am having a specific set of strings i.e. following 4 Strings

```
IDE, SATA, SSD, FLOPPY DISK
```

I want to validate all the comma separated combination of above strings irrespective of the order in which they occur and also if possible irrespective of character case they occur. For Example following should be passed

```
sata,floppy disk
IDE,SSD
SATA,ide,SSD
ssd,Floppy Disk
```

Comment: This seems like something that would be better done without regular expressions. Likely using explode and array_filter.

Comment: Also, what about duplicate values? Would `ssd,SSD, SsD` be valid?

Comment: @anubhava
I have tried 
https://regex101.com/r/BKlfBF/1/tests but it allows duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might want something like this:

```
^(?:(?:ide|sata|ssd|floppy\sdisk),)+(?:ide|sata|ssd|floppy\sdisk)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HawqE6/7)

Comment: Needs a `^` anchor for start of string or else `asdf,ide` is a match because it would match `ide` and pass.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn, missed that. Added in now.

Comment: this also allows duplicates, but still work for my need as of now, as i will filter duplicates before validation, thanks Tom

Comment: also this one allows one comma at the end of the test string, which might be a problem for me.

Comment: You're welcome @prasshant. No longer quite as clean, but I have changed it now to prevent commas at the end. Preventing duplication is much more involved though, and is (I would suspect) a job not suited best to the regex part of your use case, as you said above.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying with following Regex, so far it is handling cases, and special characters at starts but will not filter duplicates

```
^((?i)all|((IDE|SATA|SSD|FLOPPY DISK)(,(IDE|SATA|SSD|FLOPPY DISK))*))$
```

you can find above regex with some test cases at following link

https://regex101.com/r/BKlfBF/1/tests

Comment: You might want to delete this answer, and edit your original question to include this information.

Comment: above answer by @TomWyllie is allowing a comma at the end.
also I have added it so What did you try kind of questions doesn't come.